# Where to set GDB path in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ to develop on Mac. I need to set GDB path in the preferences to make debugging work but there is no place to set the path as you can see in figure:

[image]

Where is the GDP path option hidden?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late, but in my setup (also on Mac) I do see the GDB path:

[image: Eclipse GDB option]

What version are you running? I'm on Neon 4.6.0:

[image]

Comment: If you need to ask for more information, or to discuss the question further, use comments under the original question. Your answer should only be a suggested solution, not a discussion.